# Why does the use of mouseMoveEvent in my own QGraphicsView invalidate setTransformationAnchor?

Tags: python, pyqt

When I use the wheel to scale the image, the image will always be scaled with the anchor point in the upper left corner.

But when I comment out the *mouseMoveEvent* function, the image can be scaled with the mouse position as the anchor point.

Here is my code:

```
class myQGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, *__args):
        super().__init__(*__args)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(self.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.pressed = 0

        self.setMouseTracking(False)

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        print(1)
        self.pressed = 1
        self.last_mouse_x = QMouseEvent.x()
        self.last_mouse_y = QMouseEvent.y()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if self.pressed == 1:
            self.current_mouse_x = QMouseEvent.x()
            self.current_mouse_y = QMouseEvent.y()
            self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.horizontalScrollBar().value() -(self.current_mouse_x - self.last_mouse_x))
            self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(
                self.verticalScrollBar().value() - (self.current_mouse_y - self.last_mouse_y))
            # print(self.current_mouse_x - self.last_mouse_x, self.current_mouse_y - self.last_mouse_y)
            # self.img_view.translate(self.current_mouse_x - self.last_mouse_x, self.current_mouse_y - self.last_mouse_y)
            # self.img_view.translate(1, 1)
            self.last_mouse_x = self.current_mouse_x
            self.last_mouse_y = self.current_mouse_y

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        self.pressed = 0

    def wheelEvent(self, QWheelEvent):
        if QApplication.keyboardModifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            print(self.mapToScene(self.x(), self.y()))
            angle = QWheelEvent.angleDelta().y()
            if angle > 0:
                scale_factor = 1.25
            else:
                scale_factor = 0.8
            self.scale(scale_factor, scale_factor)
            ui_1.current_img_w = ui_1.current_img_w * scale_factor
            ui_1.current_img_h = ui_1.current_img_h * scale_factor
```

Comment: Not sure but I'm guessing you might need to call the base class implementation.  So add the line `super(myQGraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent)` at the beginning of `myQGraphicsView.mouseMoveEvent`.

Comment: Yes... adding this line makes the fuction works normally. Thank you very much @G.M.